# How to recursively render menu

Tags: reactjs, next.js, antd

I'm trying to recursively render [AntDesign Menu](https://ant.design/components/menu/). I found some examples how to do it based on just normal `ul` and `li` tags and they works, but when I'm trying changing `li` to `Menu.Item` and `ul` to `SubMenu` then every item is active and with wrong styles.

example data:

```json
[
    {fileName: "test1"}
    {fileName: "test2"}
    {fileName: "x",
     items: [
      {fileName: 'test3'}
    ]}
]
```

My attemp:

```
<Menu
   mode="inline"
   onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)}
   >
     {data.map((item) => (
        <ListItem item={item} />
      ))}
</Menu>
```

```
 const ListItem = ({ item }: iLProps) => {
    let children = null;
    if (item.items && item.items.length) {
      children = (
        <SubMenu key={item.fileName} title={item.fileName}>
          {item.items.map((nestedItem: NavItem) => (
            <ListItem item={nestedItem} />
          ))}
        </SubMenu>
      );
    }
    return (
      <Menu.Item key={item.fileName}>
        {item.fileName}
        {children}
      </Menu.Item>
    );
  };
```

If someone need working examples on codesandbox then I can add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me:

```js
const recursiveMenu = (data) => {
  return data.map(({ fileName, items = [] }) => {
    console.log({ fileName, items });
    if (!items?.length) {
      return <Item key={Math.random()}>{fileName}</Item>;
    }

    return (
      <SubMenu key={Math.random()} title={fileName}>
        {recursiveMenu(items)}
      </SubMenu>
    );
  });
};
```

And in the Menu component:

```js
export default function App() {
  return <Menu mode="inline">{recursiveMenu(data)}</Menu>;
}
```

Here is a working codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-wind-55otl